# Select field by type

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-implicits

I am trying to create a type class that allows to select a field for a given type. This is what I have done so far but the compiler is unable to find the Selector.Aux

```
case class AddressKey(street: String, city: String)

trait AddressKeySelector[A] {
  def addressKey(v: A): AddressKey
  def addressKeyColumnName: String
}

object AddressKeySelector {

  implicit def typeAddressKeySelector[A, Repr <: HList, K](
      implicit gen: Generic.Aux[A, Repr],
      reprSelector: Selector.Aux[Repr, K, AddressKey]): AddressKeySelector[A] =
    new AddressKeySelector[A] {
      override def addressKey(v: A): AddressKey = reprSelector(gen.to(v))

      override def addressKeyColumnName: String = ???
    }
}
```

It will be used like this

```
case class MyType(addressKeyField: AddressKey, otherField: String)
val data = MyType(AddressKey("addr", "city"), "other")
val addrKey = AddressKeySelector[MyType].addressKey(data) 
// addrKey: AddressKey = AddressKey(addr,city) 
val addrField = AddressKeySelector[MyType].addressKeyColumnName(data)
// addrField: String = addressKeyField
```

This should just work when there is one and only one field with type AddressKey. Any idea on how to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ops.hlist.Selector` doesn't have an `Aux`, so I'm assuming you're using that one. Seeing as you want to extract the field name you probably want to use `LabelledGeneric` and `ops.record.Selector` instead. But then `Selector.Aux[Repr, K, AddressKey]` would still not work because `Selector` can only search by "key" (`K`) and not by "value" (`AddressKey`) while you are searching for the key by the value.

Ideally I think you would implement it like this:

```
import shapeless._, ops.record._

trait AddressKeySelector[A] {
  def addressKey(v: A): AddressKey
  def addressKeyColumnName: String
}

object AddressKeySelector {
  def apply[A](implicit sel: AddressKeySelector[A]): sel.type = sel

  implicit def typeAddressKeySelector[A, Repr <: HList, K <: Symbol, Swapped <: HList](
      implicit 
      gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, Repr],
      swap: SwapRecord.Aux[Repr, Swapped],
      swappedSelector: Selector.Aux[Swapped, AddressKey, K],
      reprSelector: Selector.Aux[Repr, K, AddressKey]
  ): AddressKeySelector[A] =
    new AddressKeySelector[A] {
      override def addressKey(v: A): AddressKey = reprSelector(gen.to(v))

      override def addressKeyColumnName: String = swappedSelector(swap()).name
    }
}
```

But for [some reason](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/issues/732) that doesn't work.

So I think your best bet is implementing the search by value yourself. It's relatively straightforward. You can take inspiration from the [`ops.hlist.Selector`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/hlists.scala#L864). Keeping in mind that every entry in the `Hlist` that is emitted by `LabelledGeneric` is encoded as `labelled.FieldType[Key,Value]` and that you can get the runtime value of `Key` (or in other words: the field name) with `Witness.Aux[Key]`.

Comment: what is the SwapRecord type class doing?

Comment: It swaps every `FieldType[K,V]` in the `HList` to `FieldType[V,K]`.

Comment: You can only select on key. So if you swap keys and values you can select on value (which has become the key).

Comment: selecting a field by type instead of using the symbol seems to be a reasonable operation, I am surprised that there is not a type class for this

Comment: So was I. I thought it simply wasn't needed because of `SwapRecord` but that doesn't seem to work...